# Javascript .replace on Euro symbol (special characters)

Tags: javascript, replace, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to replace a euro symbol with a sterling symbol using the `.replace` method. Unfortunately it fails with `€`, `&euro` and `\u20AC` and the escaped versions.

Am i missing something or is replace unable to handle special characters?

```
function updateCurrency(elem){
    if(elem.value === 'sterling'){
        window.currency= '£';
        minValue= document.getElementById('min').value;
        minValue= minValue.replace('/&euro;', '£');
        console.log(minValue)
        maxValue= document.getElementById('max').value.replace('\u20AC', '£');
    } else {
        window.currency= '\u20AC';
        minValue= document.getElementById('min').value.replace('£', '\u20AC');
        maxValue= document.getElementById('max').value.replace('£', '\u20AC');
    }

}
```

codepen:
http://codepen.io/ambrosedheffernan/pen/PqOmMG

Comment: You forgot to define some javascript functions in your codepen (updateMinValue, updateMaxValue).

Comment: You computed the value and do a replacement in the string but forgot to update the value. Something like `document.getElementById('min').value = minValue`

Comment: @sergioFC that would be the next step alright, but `minValue = €xxxx` after the replacement (that's the value that is alerted in the codepen)...its odd that none of the codes work , `charCodeAt()` gives 8264 which doesnt work either, fortunately i can just use substring to remove the character but ill leave this up in case anyone can answer it.

Comment: minValue.replace('€', '£') works for me

Comment: @sergioFC in which browser?

Comment: Firefox 38.0 on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your updateCurrency function for this simpler one and you'll see that `€` and `£` are replaced (when switching between currencys):

```
function updateCurrency(elem){
    if(elem.value === 'sterling'){
        var newCurrency = '£';
        var oldCurrency = '€';
    }
    else {
        var newCurrency = '€'; 
        var oldCurrency = '£';         
    }

    var maxValue = document.getElementById('max').value;
    maxValue = maxValue.replace(oldCurrency, newCurrency)
    document.getElementById('max').value = maxValue;

    var minValue = document.getElementById('min').value;
    minValue = minValue.replace(oldCurrency, newCurrency)
    document.getElementById('min').value = minValue;   
}
```

Comment: hmm works in code pen but its failing on my debian server, ill look into this later in the week, but thanks for the help, at least i know its not a browser issue!

Comment: That's weird, I don't think there is something so special with those special characters, I think it should work everywhere. Please let me know when you have more info.

Comment: interesting titbit, apparently browsers ignore the charset declarations in html tags, you need to change the http charset to actually get ANSI encoding to work and then your code works perfectly (as well as allowing € character to be used.) I used php `header()` to change if it helps anyone.